# CORE::GLOBAL::die redefinition inside BEGIN

Tags: perl, die

I have the following code

```
print "Starting..\n";
eval { die "Before die sub redefinition\n" };
#die "Before die sub redefinition\n";
BEGIN {
    print "inside Begin block\n";
    *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub {
        my ($message) = @_;
        print "Message: " . $message ."\n";
    }
}
eval { die "Right after begin block\n" };
print "done\n";
```

Output is as below,

```
inside Begin block
Starting..
Message: Right after begin block

done
```

`BEGIN` block gets executed first before any other statement; however redefinition of `CORE::Global::die` is effective only after the redefinition. First `die` doesn't use the redefined version but the original. Could someone please help me figurr out the cause here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BEGIN` makes a block of code execute immediately after it's compiled, instead of waiting for the compile phase to complete. That means that code in `BEGIN` blocks executes before other code *executes*, but not necessarily before other code *compiles*. Code still compiles basically in the order that it's seen.

For a `CORE::GLOBAL` override to have effect on a given call, it has to have already been installed when that call is compiled. If there is no override, then the compiler will emit a call to the builtin core function.

All of the code in your file before the `BEGIN` block is compiled before the `BEGIN` block runs, so the first `die` call there isn't overridden.

Answer (score 3):

[hobbs already explained the compile time sequencing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64033993/2766176), but there's another point to consider if you want to redefine `die`. You don't necessarily need to reach into `CORE::` (although dealing with legacy code you can't touch is a different issue). You can install a `die` (or `warn`) handler in the `%SIG` hash:

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { ... };
```